# Time limit exceeded issue in c++ UVa problem for university homework

Tags: c++

I have a Time limit exceeded issue in problem 100 from UVa.

the question is here:
https://onlinejudge.org/index.php?option=com_onlinejudge&Itemid=8&category=24&page=show_problem&problem=36

Here is my code. Please help me find a solution. How can I avoid such problems?
I don't know if it is the problem with cin and cout or the while loops? this program works well in my terminal when I run it.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int i , j, temp, n;
    while (cin >> i >> j) //asking for user input
{
    int x, y;
    x = i;
    y = j;

    if (i > j) //sorting i and j to fix the order of numbers
    {
        temp = j;
        j = i;
        i = temp; 
    }

    int answer = 0;
    int counter;

    while (i <= j)
    {
        n = i;
        counter = 1; // make the value of counter to 1 because it increases if i is 1

        while (1)
        {
            if(n == 1) { //if n = 1 then stop
                break;
            } else if (n % 2 == 0) //cheak if i is odd
            {
                n = (3 % n) + 1;
            } else {
                n = n / 2;  //cheak if i is even
            }
            counter++; //increase by one for every number that is not 1
        }

        if (counter > answer)
        {
            answer = counter;
        }
        i++;  
    }
    cout << x << " " << y << " " << answer << "\n";
}
return 0;
```

}

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: the online judge did not accept the code because of Time exceeded issue. Otherwise, the program works. I don't know what can I do to fix this issue

Comment: I mean, what is the problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: sorry. it is this problem: https://onlinejudge.org/index.php?option=com_onlinejudge&Itemid=8&category=24&page=show_problem&problem=36

Comment: This almost sounds like more of a math problem than it does a programming problem. Your programming solution is a brute force check of the maximum cycle length -- while the problem hints that the cycle length should be capable of being determined without that approach. At least that's what I took from the read.

Comment: If you have `n == 2`, you do `n = (3 % n) + 1`, which is 2, and then... (You misspelled `*`.)

Answer (score 1):

In my humble opinion this problem is not about calculating the resulting values using the given algorithm. Because of the simplicity this is just some noise. So,maybe we are talking about a [XY Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem) here.

Maybe I am wrong, but the main problem here seems to be memoization.

It maybe that values need to be calculated over and over again, because they are in some overlapped range. And this is not necessary.

So, we could memorize already calculated values, for example in a `std::unordered_map` (or `std::map`). So, something like in the below:

```
unsigned int getSteps(size_t index) noexcept {
    unsigned counter{};
    while (index != 1) {
        if (index % 2) index = index * 3 + 1;
        else index /= 2;
        ++counter;
    }
    return counter+1;
}

unsigned int getStepsMemo(size_t index) {
    // Here we will memorize whatever we calculated before
    static std::unordered_map<unsigned int, unsigned int> memo{};

    // Resulting value
    unsigned int result{};

    // Look, if we did calculate the value in the past
    auto iter = memo.find(index);
    if (iter != memo.end()) 

        // If yes, then reuse old value
        result = iter->second;
    else {
        // If no, then calculate new and memorize it
        result = getSteps(index);
        memo[index] = result;
    }
    return result;
}
```

This will help with many given input pairs. It will avoid recalculating steps for already calculated values.

But having thought in this direction, we can also calculate **all** values at compile time and store them in a `constexpr std::array`. Then no calculation will be done during runtime. All steps for any number up to 10000 will be precalculated. So, the algorithm will never be called during runtime.

It should be clear that this is the fastest possible algorithm, because we do nothing. Just get the value from a lookup table.

And if we want to make things nice, then we pack everything in a class and let the class encapsulate the problem. Even input and output operatores will be overwritten and used for our own purposes.

And in the end, we will have an ultra fast one liner in our function main. Please see:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>
#include <sstream>
#include <array>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <unordered_map>

// All done during compile time -------------------------------------------------------------------
constexpr unsigned int getSteps(size_t index) noexcept {
    unsigned counter{};
    while (index != 1) {
        if (index % 2) index = index * 3 + 1;
        else index /= 2;
        ++counter;
    }
    return counter+1;
}
// Some helper to create a constexpr std::array initilized by a generator function
template <typename Generator, size_t ... Indices>
constexpr auto generateArrayHelper(Generator generator, std::index_sequence<Indices...>) {
    return std::array<decltype(std::declval<Generator>()(size_t{})), sizeof...(Indices) > { generator(Indices+1)... };
}
template <size_t Size, typename Generator>
constexpr auto generateArray(Generator generator) {
    return  generateArrayHelper(generator, std::make_index_sequence<Size>());
}
constexpr size_t MaxIndex = 10000;

// This is the definition of a std::array<unsigned long long, 10000> with all step counts
constexpr auto steps = generateArray<MaxIndex>(getSteps);
// End of: All done during compile time -----------------------------------------------------------

// Some very simple helper class for easier handling of the functionality
struct StepsForPair {
    // A pair with special functionality
    unsigned int first{};
    unsigned int second{};
    
    // Simple extraction operator. Read 2 values
    friend std::istream& operator >> (std::istream& is, StepsForPair& sfp) {
        return is >> sfp.first >> sfp.second;
    }
    // Simple inserter. Sort first and second value and show result
    friend std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& os, const StepsForPair& sfp) {
        unsigned int f{ sfp.first }, s{ sfp.second };
        if (f > s) std::swap(f, s);
        return os << sfp.first << ' ' << sfp.second << ' ' << *std::max_element(&steps[f], &steps[s]);
    }
};
// Some test data. I will not use std::cin, but read from this std::istringstream here
std::istringstream testData{ R"(1 10
100 200
201 210
900 1000
22 22)" };

int main() {

    // Read all input data and generate output
    std::copy(std::istream_iterator<StepsForPair>(testData), {}, std::ostream_iterator<StepsForPair>(std::cout,"\n"));
}
```

Please note, since I do not have `std::cin` here on SO, I read the test values from a `std::istringstream`. Because of the overwritten extractor operator, this is easily possible.

If you want to read from `std::cin` then please replace in the `std::copy` statement in main "testData" eith "std::cin".

If you want to read from a file, then put a fileStream variable in there.

Comment: you can  use memoized values within GetSteps: as the algorithm hits an already known value, you already know how many further step you need.
If I'm not missing something your memoizations works only if you call GetSteps twice or more with the same value (not a use case for the input values im the example

Comment: You miss the major point. You are correct for the first example. But this is just an example. The main code at the bottom, does a compile time pre calculation of all 10k results. The function get Steps will never be called at all during runtime, because the values are already known. So, we do a compile time memoization . . .

Comment: Sure, the compile time version will run in no time. I was talking about the first version, where If I'm not wrong the memoizaton suggested does not get the desired performance boost

Answer (score 0):

In this line `n = (3 % n) + 1;`, `(3 % n)` means that you take the *remainder* of 3 divided by n, which is probably not what you want. Change that to 3 * n